# Does TD(0) require Robbins-Monro condition on learning rate parameter?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

For one step Temporal Difference Learning does the learning rate parameter $\alpha$ require the Robbins-Monro condition?

$$ \sum \alpha_t =\infty \quad \text{and}\quad \sum \alpha^{2}_t <\infty$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original proof for TD(0) given in [1] is a proof for convergence in the mean. Since this is not convergence in probability, there is no need for the Robbins-Monro conditions. However, there is a proof for convergence in probability given in [2] that does require the Robbins-Monro conditions to hold.

[1] Sutton, R. S. (1988). Learning to predict by the methods of temporal
  differences. Machine learning, 3(1), 9–44.

[2] Dayan, P. (1992). The convergence of td ($\lambda$) for general $\lambda$.
  Machine learning, 8(3-4), 341–362.